# get opening tag including attributes - outerHTML without innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, innerhtml, outerhtml

I would like to retrieve a certain tag element with its attributes from the DOM. For example, from

```
<a href="#" class="class">
  link text
</a>
```

I want to get `<a href="#" class="class">`, optionally with a closing `</a>`, either as a string or some other object.
In my opinion, this would be similar to retrieving the `.outerHTML` without the `.innerHTML`.

Finally, I need this to wrap some other elements via jQuery. I tried

```
var elem = $('#some-element').get(0);
$('#some-other-element').wrap(elem);
```

but `.get()` returns the DOM element including its content. Also

```
var elem = $('#some-element').get(0);
$('#some-other-element').wrap(elem.tagName).parent().attr(elem.attributes);
```

fails as `elem.attributes` returns a `NamedNodeMap` which does not work with jQuery's `attr()` and I was not able to convert it.
Admitted that the above examples are not very senseful as they copy also the element's no-longer-unique ID. But is there any easy way? Thanks alot.

Comment: Just clone node with `.clone()`, then empty it with `.html()` and remove `id` and what else you want.

Comment: $("a").clone().empty().attr("outerHTML");  To solve first problem

Comment: Thanks @kirilloid, guess josh was just quicker ;)

Comment: Thanks also @UlhasTuscano, should work great in conjunction with some outerHTML workarounds, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var wrapper = $('.class').clone().attr('id','').empty();
```

- You might want to change the selector to more exactly match the `<a>` element you're looking for.
- [`clone()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=clone) creates a new copy of the matched element(s), optionally copying event handlers too.
- I used `attr` to clear the element's ID so that we don't duplicate IDs.
- [`empty()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=empty) removes all child nodes (the '`innerHTML`').

Comment: Amazing. Thanks very much, josh :) Any concerns about using `.clone()`? Some say it may not be that performant, but I cannot see any other solution.

Comment: i guess .clone() isn'e exactly copy the whole object and some sort of reference do exists and if we use .remove() to the cloned object, it actually removes the original object. I suffer this issue once.

Comment: @RichardKiefer: Performance is obviously browser-dependent, but this code [ranges from 3,000 ops/sec in IE8 to 25,000 ops/sec in FF10](http://jsperf.com/jq-clone-perf).  You probably shouldn't be generating thousands of DOM elements anyway, so I don't see anything to worry about.

Answer (score 18):

There is a way to do this without jQuery.
This also works with `<br>` tags, `<meta>` tags, and other empty tags:

```
tag = elem.innerHTML ? elem.outerHTML.slice(0,elem.outerHTML.indexOf(elem.innerHTML)) : elem.outerHTML;
```

Because innerHTML would be empty in self-closing tags, and `indexOf('')` always returns 0, the above modification checks for the presence of `innerHTML` first.

Comment: This doesn't work with empty elements: document.createElement("strong").outerHTML.slice(0, elem.outerHTML.indexOf(elem.innerHTML))

Comment: @Martin put your `createElement` declaration in a variable called `elem` and use the ternary expression I used above, it returns `<strong></strong>`.

Comment: @AaronGillion Good catch. That one could be remedied by searching for `><` if innerHTML is an empty string. This makes me think of another issue, though: `<span id="space"> </span>` identifies the wrong index for the space.

Comment: ***This is very UNSAFE***. E. g. when **`elem.outerHTML === '<p>p</p>'`**. Or any other situation that innerHTML's text is a subset of tagName or one of its attributes or even attributes' values!

Comment: as another comment said: very **Unsafe** -- if **multiple** other text has the **same** content of innerHtml... otherwise (if you dont care that, and dont care empty tags), wouldnt `split()` be a lot easier?...

Answer (score 4):

If someone is not using jQuery . . .

```
elem.outerHTML
"<a href="#" class="class">
  link text
</a>"
elem.cloneNode().outerHTML
"<a href="#" class="class"></a>"
```

If you want to be safe for Firefox etc. released before mid-2014, use cloneNode(false) to avoid getting inner stuff.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: This is the correct answer. All the other distracting answers should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```js
opentag=elem.outerHTML.slice(0, elem.outerHTML.length-elem.innerHTML.length-elem.tagName.length-3);
```

I suppose, that close tag is of the form: `"</"+elem.tagName+">"`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [@AaronGillion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639030/5318303) isn't reliable as I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604235/get-opening-tag-including-attributes-outerhtml-without-innerhtml#comment98376766_34639030). Thank [@sus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10478326/sus). I recommend [his/her way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720414/5318303) with a little change to support `<self-closing tags />`:

```js
function getOpenTag(element: HTMLElement): string {
    const outerHtml = element.outerHTML;
    const len = outerHtml.length;
    
    const openTagLength = outerHtml[len - 2] === '/' ? // Is self-closing tag?
            len :
            len - element.innerHTML.length - (element.tagName.length + 3);
    // As @sus said, (element.tagName.length + 3) is the length of closing tag. It's always `</${tagName}>`. Correct?
    
    return outerHtml.slice(0, openTagLength);
}
```

<sup>*The code is in TypeScript. Remove types (`HTMLElement` and `number`) if you want JavaScript.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I've used:

```
const wrap = document.createElement('div')
wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true))
const openingTag = wrap.innerHTML.split('>')[0] + '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any String manipulation.

Instead, you can use the element's internals and build the string yourself from there:

```js
function getTagHTML(el) {
  if (!el instanceof HTMLElement) return null;
  let result = `<${el.tagName.toLowerCase()}`;
  for (const attribute in el.attributes) {
    if (el.attributes[attribute].nodeValue) 
      result += ` ${el.attributes[attribute].name}="${el.attributes[attribute].nodeValue.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")}"`
  }
  result += `></${el.tagName.toLowerCase()}>`;
  return result;
}

console.log(getTagHTML(document.getElementById('outer')));
```

```html
<div id="outer" class='i-want-"this"'>
  <span>I do not want this</span>
</div>
```

Please note that for self-closing elements like `<img />` this would give you an unwanted and incorrect closing tag. Feel free to adjust the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for cloneNode answer above

- create HTML without content
- Looping over attributes
- **optional end tag**
- **optional self-closing tag**

```js
function getTagHTML(el, includeClosingTag=true , selfClosing = false) {
  //return el.cloneNode(false).outerHTML;
  if (el.attributes)
    return `<${el.localName}` + 
      [...el.attributes].map(
             attr => ` ${attr.name}="${attr.nodeValue.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")}"`
      ).join`` +
      `${selfClosing ? "/" : ""}>` + 
      (!selfClosing && includeClosingTag ? `</${el.localName}>` : "");
  else 
    return null;
}

document.body.querySelectorAll("*:not(script)").forEach(el=>{
  console.log(getTagHTML(el));
  console.log(getTagHTML(el,false));
  console.log(getTagHTML(el,false,true))
});
```

```html
<div id="ONE" class='CLASSNAMES' attr1='"string"'>
   INNERHTML
  </div>
  <img id="TWO" src="https://svgshare.com/i/Uhq.svg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using Reg Exp to replace all possible closing tags inside element attributes:

```
const outerHTML = div.outerHTML;
const content = outerHTML.slice(0, outerHTML.length - div.innerHTML.length);
const dummy = content.replace(/'.*?'|".*?"/g, x => 'x'.repeat(x.length));
return content.slice(0, 1 + dummy.indexOf('>'));
```